# Unable to insert values in my database using XAMPP server in my android application

Tags: php, android, database, json, xampp

Im new to coding in android. I'm not able to insert values in my database though the logcat shows that i have inserted in it, yet database is unable to show the values which i have inserted. Attaching all codes herewith:

AlertDialogManager.java

```
public class AlertDialogManager extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputQty;
EditText inputPrice;


// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/Schemes_NAV/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_date_entry);

    // Edit Text
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_price);
    inputQty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_qty);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OkButton);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlertDialogManager.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String Qty = inputQty.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Qty", Qty));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));


        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Nav.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

Next is its layout i.e. alert_dialog_text_date_entry.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_qty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:imeActionLabel="Done"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:numeric="decimal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_price"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:imeActionLabel="Done"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:numeric="decimal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Buy Date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/et_datePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
       android:layout_width="302dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/OkButton"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
    android:text="OK" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
    android:text="Cancel" />

  </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Next, the php file create_product.php

```
<?php

  // array for JSON response
  $response = array();

 // check for required fields
 if (isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['price'])) {

$Qty = $_POST['Qty'];
$price = $_POST['price'];


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO schemes(Qty, price) VALUES('$Qty', '$price')");


// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And, the logcat which indeed shows that it has created new product.

```
 D/dalvikvm(686): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6754 objects / 755288 bytes in 236ms
 03-29 15:40:09.499: D/Create Response(686): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
```

Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: what is problem here ?

Comment: the database isn't showing the values which I'm trying to insert in "schemes" table.

Comment: Create static URL and check in browser , whether its work or not ? So, you can get idea problem is in android side or PHP side

Answer (score 0):

You need to move below two statements from doInBackground to onPreExecute method.

```
String Qty = inputQty.getText().toString();
String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
```

doInBackground runs on different thread and hence does not have access to your activity view while onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods runs on your UI/Main thread and can access Activity View.

Your server side code does not validates any input it receives. In your code, doInBackground sends blank values for Quantity and Price and with these options a row with blank values will be inserted if there is no database constrains on these fields.